# changing eclipse's java compiler to jdk7

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, java-7

I'm trying to upgrade from jre6 and jdk6 to jre7 and jdk7.
I program using eclipse, i downloaded and installed the jre7 and jdk7 on:
C:\program files\java\
now when I enter eclipse i want to change the used compiler so i go to:
window>preferences>java>compiler
but there appears only 1.3,1.4,1.5 and 1.6
I've also entered:
window>preferences>java>Installed JREs
and added the jre7 version. But the compiler I can't change.
how do I change my eclipse compiler?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to upgrade to at least [Eclipse Indigo SR1](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), which has been out for over a month. See also [Eclipse announces full Java 7 support](http://eclipse.org/org/press-release/20110929_indigosr1.php).

As evidence, here's a screen from my Indigo SR1 preferences:

[image]

And here's an example of executabele code snippet using diamond operator and ARM:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need a newer version of Eclipse.  At least 3.7SR1.

Comment: That's wrong, Eclipse 3.7 SR1 supports all JDK 7 features.

Answer (score 0):

3.6 Eclipse version is enough. I`m using the same with JDK1.7

Comment: A screenshot to prove this is correct would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Window > Preferences >Java > Installed JREs`.

Then click `Add...` and select `Standard VM`.

You need to specify the directory of your JRE and give it a name.

When you are done, just check the right JRE in the same window.

By default, the checked JRE is added to the build path of newly created Java projects.

(my Eclipse SDK version is 3.7.0)

Comment: This doesn't add compiler support for Java 1.7.