# Replacing Java 7 with Java 6

Tags: java, java-6, java-7

Currently I am running java 7 on Windows 7

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)
```

How can i replace it with Java 6 ?? What is the best way ??

Comment: Well, install Java 6? Not sure what you mean by "replace".

Comment: or just use javac target option to be backward compatible

Comment: What do you mean? Just uninstall Java 7 and install Java 6.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Java 6 SE is [scheduled to be EOLed](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) in November 2012, anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Java 6 from the Sun website

Then change the PATH to point to Java 6.

Or you could have followed this guide: [Java Website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-137561.html)

Comment: If we change the JDK version do we need to configure Eclipse to use JDK 6 instead of 7 ?

Comment: [Previous Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022233/changing-eclipses-java-compiler-to-jdk7)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to change that - with the latest version (7 at the moment) you can run code compiled for all older versions, AND for the newest version.

What you probably want is to compile your code for use with a older version. See the [cross-compilation example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-example) how to do it with the `javac` command, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022233/changing-eclipses-java-compiler-to-jdk7) for how to do it in eclipse.