# Multiple markers at this line - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected - Syntax error on token "(", { expected

Tags: java, java-7, parentheses, try-finally

I'm studying Java (sorry for my poor english, it's not my native language) and when I do a "try-finally" block in Eclipse (JavaSE-1.7) in every "try" that I put, appears this message:

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
>     - Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete     BlockStatements

Here is the full code:

```
package Java;

public class Arquivo3 {

    private Path BdC = Paths.get("C:/xti/files/conta.txt");
    private Charset utf8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

    public void armazenarContas(ArrayList<Conta> contas) throws IOException{                
        try(BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(BdC, utf8)) {
            for (Conta conta : contas) {
                writer.write(conta.getCliente() + ";" + conta.getSaldo() + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Conta> recuperarContas() throws IOException{
        ArrayList<Conta> contas = new ArrayList<Conta>();
        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(BdC, utf8)){
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] t = line.split(";");
                Conta conta = new Conta(t[0], Double.parseDouble(t[1]));
                contas.add(conta);
            }
        }finally {
        return contas;  
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
/*
        ArrayList<Conta> contas = new ArrayList<Conta>();
        contas.add(new Conta("Ricardo", 12000.23));
        contas.add(new Conta("Lawrence", 11050.32));
        contas.add(new Conta("Sandra", 18000.21));
        contas.add(new Conta("Beatriz", 23200.09));
    */  
        Arquivo3 operacao = new Arquivo3();
        //operacao.armazenarContas(contas);
        ArrayList<Conta> contas2 = operacao.recuperarContas();
        for (Conta conta : contas2) {
            conta.exibeSaldo();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like Eclipse is using java 1.6 not 1.7 for its code hints.

Comment: Your IDE is using jdk6.  Please fix that. .  Answers below are relevant only to java6.

Answer (score 1):

Using the comment from OP

> @yan Odd, I use jdk7 and this works for me, but then, maybe eclipse
>   uses jdk6 for testing for syntax errors. – gangqinlaohu 2 hours ago

That is correct.   You are using some jdk7 features but eclipse is configured to use jdk6 (or older).  Here are the instructions to enable jdk7 with eclipse (  [changing eclipse's java compiler to jdk7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022233/changing-eclipses-java-compiler-to-jdk7) ).

Specifically, compliance setting.

Answer (score 0):

As Eclipse says, in your `armazenarContas()` method you do not finish your [`try{}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) statement with a `finally` (or anything else for that matter). You need to add either a [`catch{}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) or a [`finally{}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) at the end of your `try{}`.

Your syntax should be something like:

```
try {
//Do stuff
} catch (ExceptionType name) {
//If an exception occours, you can handle it here.
}
```

or:

```
try {
//Do stuff
} finally {
//Everything in this block of code will be excecuted
}
```

or you can even [combine them all](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/putItTogether.html):

```
try{
//Do stuff
} catch (ExceptionType name) {
//If you get an exception
} finally {
//Always excecuted
}
```

Comment: OP is using java 7 try-with-resources, where this is not needed. He should just enable java 7 compliance though eclipse settings.