# Unable to evaluate String class in switch statement in JRE7

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

I am trying to build a simple program that demonstrate the use of the String class being evaluated in a switch statement but i'm getting a compilation error because this feature requires Java SE 7 (whish is installed in my computer).

Error message on line 5: Cannot switch on a value of type String. Only convertible int values or enum cons tants are permitted

Is Eclipse pointing at JRE7 ? = YES .
Is Environnement variable Pointing at JDK7 =YES .

java -version = OK (see pict below).
[image]

I even tried to compile the code with the console prompt. See error:
[image]

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SwitchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name = "georges";

        switch (name.toLowerCase()) {


        case "Jhon":
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Good morning, Jhon!");
         break;
      case "georges":
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "How's it going, georges?");
         break;
      case "sergei":
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "sergei, my old sergei!");
          break;
      case "Steph":
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Afternoon lennert, how's the Steph?");
          break;
      default:
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pleased to meet you, xxxxxx.");
           break;
   }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The name of your main class is `SwitchDemo`, not `switchDemo`

Comment: Absolutely. It works now but only when i compile with cmd. But Eclipse keeps showing a compile error though. Perhaps i should restart my computer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your command line I see that you run `java -cp .switchDemo`, while your actual class name is **SwitchDemo**. Notice that Java is case sensitive, thus `SwitchDemo != switchDemo`.

**From your comments:**

> Eclipse keeps returning the error message. I'm currently on Eclipse
>   Helios. I'll switch over to Juno. Thank you

you have to change your compiler to 1.7 in eclipse:

[image]

Comment: Eclipse keeps returning the error message. I'm currently on Eclipse Helios. I'll switch over to Juno. Thank you

Comment: @Rahoul not required. i guess you need to update your compiler to jdk 1.7.

Comment: The 1.7 is not present in my list. Only up to 1.6.   Please see new screenshot.

Comment: You have to use a more recent version of Eclipse.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022233/changing-eclipses-java-compiler-to-jdk7?rq=1