# How can I tell if my eclipse is using 1.7 or 1.8 for my project?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm not sure I have my client set up right, but I want to set my client to run on 1.7 for all projects but I'm not sure which it's using

Comment: I also need to run the google engine plugin which only allows 1.7

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022233/changing-eclipses-java-compiler-to-jdk7