# Gradle,- bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, weblogic12c

One thing I'd observed while compiling my Application using Gradle build is,

```
:edb-core:compileJavawarning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
C:\java_dev\projects\workspace\FY18R3_edb\edb-core\dao\dell\services\dfsl\dao\LDAPEmployeeDao.java:16: warning: LdapCtxFactory is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
import com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory;
                        ^
C:\java_dev\projects\workspace\FY18R3_edb\edb-core\dao\dell\services\dfsl\dao\LDAPEmployeeDao.java:74: warning: LdapCtxFactory is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, LdapCtxFactory.class.getName());
                                                     ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 warnings
```

Does this error has any significance, because I couldn't make my Weblogic AS up & running under eclipse ide.

> Error(s) found in module 'edb-core'. Publish was cancelled. See
>   "Problems" view for details. cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching
>   wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element
>   'ehcache:annotation-driven'. at app-config-test-virtual.xml
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no
>   declaration can be found for element 'ehcache:annotation-driven'. at
>   app-config.xml cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is
>   strict, but no declaration can be found for element
>   'ehcache:annotation-driven'. at app-config-test-dao.xml

How could I get ridden out of this problem `Gradle,-  bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7`

I'd followed this topic to set compilation with Java 1.7, however the problem persists.

[changing eclipse's java compiler to jdk7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022233/changing-eclipses-java-compiler-to-jdk7)

Comment: I'd followed this Topic which gave a necessary salvation for JDK 1.7 path fix for Gradle, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679593/gradle-compilejava-task-warning-options-bootstrap-class-path-not-set-in-conju, We just need to JDK path appropriately in `Gradle Eclipse Preference`.

Comment: Regards to `LdapCtxFactory` the prob. relies, which I need to fix soon apart, but that's different & needs salvation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In build.gradle, try to set:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
```